# While Loop or not - System resources usage

Tags: bash, loops, cpu

I am doing bash scripting and I came up with interesting question
To use While and if I use while loop how this effects the system's load CPU
While loop is executed/checked every CPU tact/cycle - so the cpu is not Idle -right?
I did a little ping pong effect with wwwhat() and ww() - means that the CPU will be idle while waiting for input from the user? I would like to know if this is better performance solution sometime than using a Loop (C,C++,Java etc)?

```
#!bin/bash


wwwhat(){
read x
if [ "$x" == "y" ]; then echo "Starting WEB SERVER"; service httpd start 2> /dev/null;
echo "Loading web site in 10sec with w3m"
sleep 10
w3m 127.0.0.1
exit
fi
if [ "$x" == "n" ]; then echo "End";
else ww; # ask Y or N
fi
}



sstartw(){
echo;
}


ww(){         #back to wwwhat
echo "y/n?:"
wwwhat;
}


clear
printf "TODAY: "; date;
echo
s="WHOAMI: ";printf "$s " ;whoami;
echo
h="HOSTNAME: "; printf "$h " ; hostname
echo
a="1";
if service httpd status > /dev/null ; then printf "WEB SERVER IS RUNNING";
echo
echo "Loading web site in 10sec with w3m"
sleep 10
w3m 127.0.0.1
fi
if ! service httpd status > /dev/null ; then printf "WEB SERVER IS DOWN";
echo
echo "Do you want to start the WEB SERVER?(y/n)"; wwwhat;
fi
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's not a `while` loop, that's a pile of spaghetti code *impersonating* a `while` loop.

Comment: yes, it is not a while loop - why you were thinking that it must be a while loop in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, if bash is waiting for user input, the while loop will not consume CPU.